# What if my server not supporting GCC 4.7? sassc bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

i have problem with installing Rails on my server.
My server is not supporting GCC 4.7, i have only GCC 4.3.2.

I've read that unrecognized command line option "-flto" is a problem with GCC directly

When i install Rails, it shows me an error:

```
Installing sassc 2.2.1 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /home/users/rails/.gems/gems/sassc-2.2.1/ext
/opt/ruby-2.5.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20191129-24208-1qqnsyr.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/users/rails/.gems/gems/sassc-2.2.1/ext
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/users/rails/.gems/gems/sassc-2.2.1/ext
make "DESTDIR="
compiling ./libsass/src/cencode.c
cc1: error: unrecognized command line option "-flto"
make: *** [cencode.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /home/users/rails/.gems/gems/sassc-2.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/users/rails/.gems/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0-static/sassc-2.2.1/gem_make.out
```

Support told me, they can install 4.7 because they would need to rebuild almost half of libraries.

Is there easy way to fix this error? 
What if i will exclude sassc from my installation? If this is a good idea, how can i do it?

I dont have this library in my Gemfile, can i delete those gems from my .gems folder? (i'm not that experienced in Ruby yet).

Thank you for your help

Comment: what is your server platform?

Comment: Server works on Debian 7, support told me, this system is strongly modified tho

Comment: I meant WHO is your host provider?  Cloud?  Metal? Can your ruby environment be dockerized?

Answer (score 0):

The option `-flto` is a link-time optimization flag. You do not need it. This flag is set in the sassc [`extconf.rb`](https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby/blob/920f36ec7bd0fff3565bf425b58b67f5873538b3/ext/extconf.rb#L28) file, and can be disabled by doing:

```
export CONFIGURE_ARGS=--disable-lto
```

And then you can proceed to install Rails as normal.

Comment: could you help me more? i googled, and couldn't find how to use command, you wrote here :) i've tried just paste it in terminal in different paths, and then i wrote something like gem install gem install sassc -v 2.0.1--disable-lto, unfortunately it didn't work

Comment: You just type it in the terminal, and then in the same terminal you run your `gem install` command. This should work on Linux with Sassc 2.1.0. Sassc 2.0.1 does not have -flto as far as I could tell. At least I could not see this option in that extconf.rb.

Comment: Can not help you with 2.0.1, as it seems to have a completely different build system. Not sure where 2.2.0 came from either, as I can not find it on Rubygems. Sorry. That's all I have at the moment.

Comment: If you cannot get it to work. I suggest open a ticket on Github with Rails or with Sassc. If you get a solution then post an answer here.

Comment: Ok. I figured out where to get 2.2.1 from. It should work with 2.2.1 also.

Comment: Removing `lto` flag alone will not help you much, as libsass (which is the library sassc uses) needs a recent compiler with good C++11 support. On the other hand it is possible to have multiple GCC versions installed on one system at the same time. So the claim of your hoster seems rather just an excuse or they really don't know how linux works. You could even try to compile a newer GCC version with your existing GCC yourself, but that might prove quite difficult for a beginner.